# PHP Curl not executing

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to retrieve the HTML from a user profile on Instagram using cURL.

I am new to cURL so do not know the cause of this error.

Nothing happens when the cURL is executed , the page seems to refresh?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.instagram.com/zohebchaudhry1/'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiess.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiess.txt');
curl_setopt($ch ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 10);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36" );
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

above is the PHP cURL code.

Comment: Try `echo htmlentities( $html );` as your last line.

Comment: Seems like it worked! Can you explain why the use of the htmlentities function is required?

Comment: It escapes `<` so your browser doesn't treat it as HTML. There may be a redirect in the `<head>` or in a `<script>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that cURL is working, however you're unable to see the output because printing HTML may not be desired.

> I suggest replacing **`echo $html;`** with **`echo htmlentities($html);`**

Read more: [php.net/htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: dunno about the downvote, but you probably want htmlentities($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);

Comment: Good recommendation @hanshenrik. `ENT_DISALLOWED` Replaces code points that are invalid in the specified doctype with a Unicode Replacement. It should be noted that it also only works with PHP 5.4.0 or later. **[Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp)**